# Missing value in formatted date column not found by is.na

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to run a regression on a data series. I want to analyse what happens to a client before the actual sale.

For clients that purchased, I want to stop collecting data two weeks prior to the sale date for each client.

For clients that didn't purchase, I want to use all the data available.

I'm using the code below (the formatting of the dates is how I get them from the system I'm extracting the data):

```
library(dplyr)

# create the sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  client_id = c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5),
  int_type = c("chat", "chat", "chat", "chat", "chat", "sale", "sale", "chat"),
  int_date = c("03OCT2017:17:07:59.000", "06OCT2017:16:50:55.000", "07MAR2017:10:29:02.000",
               "13FEB2017:06:02:07.000", "16APR2017:17:20:36.000", "22APR2017:13:04:12.000",
               "25JUN2017:12:45:33.000", "27JUN2017:15:02:04.000")
  )

# create a column converting strings to dates
df$int_date_posix <- as.POSIXct(df$int_date, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

# group and summarize to get sale dates
df <- group_by(df, client_id)
df2 <- summarize(df, dt_sale = max(int_date_posix[int_type=="sale"]))

# merge with original data frame
df <- merge(df, df2, by="client_id", all.x=T, all.y=F)
rm(df2)

df <- mutate(df, int_from_sale = difftime(dt_sale, int_date_posix, units="days"))

# filter out everything that happened after two weeks prior to sales
df2 <- df[which(
  df$int_from_sale>14 |
  is.na(df$dt_sale)
  ),]
```

This correctly filters out the data for the clients that purchased, but does not include any client that didn't purchase, even though I included an is.na term in the filter.

I can see that is.na does not understand that the NA value in the first row of dt_sale is actually an NA.

```
> df[1,"dt_sale"]
[1] NA
> is.na(df[1,"dt_sale"])
[1] FALSE
```

I can't figure out a function that would return TRUE for this value, and thus let me filter the data frame as I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run into an issue when you define df2 as you do above:

```
> df2 <- summarize(df, dt_sale = max(int_date_posix[int_type=="sale"]))
Warning messages:
1: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Because of this circumstance, you can use `is.infinite()`:

```
> is.infinite(df$dt_sale)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```